# Select opening hours easily with a grid and jquery?

Tags: jquery, plugins, time

I was looking at different approaches  to make it easy for users to setup their opening hours on a website. I was ending up with the solution like in this image:

[image]

So basically there is a grid with half hour steps and rows for each day. Now you should be able to click on 08:00 and drag the mouse over to 12:00 for setting the time you're available.

I think this is most intuitiv way, instead of adding "time slots" with some kind of a form.

Do you know any plugin (like for jQuery) that serves this ability?

Thanks for any hint in the right direction!

Greetings

Comment: I can't seem to find much out there to match your need surprisingly. I would expect it to be some kind of canvas element you drop on your page though. Might be something I look into further actually.

Comment: @JokerDan: Yeah I was wondering too. Kinda a basic functionality. I'm looking into a solution with a standard calender now, where the user add "opening blocks" in form of an event. this would make it quit easy to modify the times as well. What do you think?

Comment: I have started to throw together a basic click implementation of what you want. Ill may work on it further, time permitting, when I'm home.

Comment: @JokerDan: Did you workout something yet? Still stack on this one. Greetings

Comment: ExecutoR : This is a very crude, basic fiddle I threw together but needs to be worked on in terms of lifting data off the grid. Currently it works off the static HTML but realistically I would have it initialised through javascript. Sadly time is no on my side right now but try your best to hack at it. https://jsfiddle.net/JokerDan/ey414evt/1/

Comment: @JokerDan Thats a really good starting point. I'll try to work on this as well asap! Thx

Answer (score 0):

You might want to give [dragula](https://bevacqua.github.io/dragula/) a try.

Docs are [here](https://github.com/bevacqua/dragula#drakeon-events).

It will be up to you to decide on what happens when these events are fired but I think this will help you at least enable drag and drop support for now.

Comment: thanks for the answer. I tried already different drag&drop plugins but they all hook up on the element you click on. that's not working as intended.